# Truffle test resources

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I'm looking for some guide that drive me into solidity + truffle unit test (best practice, etc...). The only doc that I have found is the official doc.

Comment: Not exactly "best practices" but this cheat sheet works for me. http://chaijs.com/api/assert/  Truffle has not invented it, per se, so consider searching instead for Mocha. The new solidity testing is not yet documented beyond read Assert.sol.

Comment: You might be able to apply some of the same practices I used when writing a [proof-of-concept Lottery app](https://github.com/DeviateFish/Lotto/tree/master/test/unit).  I wrote about some of the problems I ran into when writing unit tests with `embark` in a [Medium post](https://medium.com/@deviatefish/building-a-lottery-part-2-c4dffd118850).  Not directly useful since you're using a different framework, but perhaps useful information to have on hand.

Comment: Anyone have an update on this?